# "this" dentro de propriedades de objetos

Tags: javascript, this

No código abaixo, o primeiro `console.log(this)` retorna o objeto `example` (até aí tudo certo). O segundo `console.log(this)` retorna o objeto `window`.

Por que isso acontece? Por que, mesmo dentro de um objeto, `let f2` vai para o contexto global?

Na minha concepção inicial, por estar dentro do contexto de execução de `f1`, o `this` deveria permanecer o mesmo.

```js
let example = {
  f1: function() {
    console.log(this);
    let f2 = function() {
      console.log(this);
    }
    f2();
  }
}
example.f1();
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSp4t.jpg

Comment: é o famoso escopo ...

Comment: boa leitura: https://imasters.com.br/desenvolvimento/escopos-em-javascript

Answer (score 5):

Em um método, o `this` referencia o objeto dono do método. Em uma função "normal" referencia o objeto global (digo "normal" porque não é uma função de método ou evento).

No seu exemplo, o primeiro `this` está dentro do método `f1`, logo esse `this` é o objeto `example` (dono de `f1`):

```js
let example = {
  f1: function() {
    console.log(this);
    let f2 = function() {
      console.log(this);
    }
    //f2();
  }
}
example.f1();
```

Veja acima que ele retorna o conteúdo de `example`.

Já no segundo `this`, como está dentro da função `f2` (que é uma função normal qualquer com o nome `f2`), retorna o objeto global. O `this` é "escopado" dentro da função, ou seja, o `this` dentro de `f2` nada tem a ver com o `this` dentro de `f1`, mesmo este estando dentro daquele.

Se o `this` estivesse num evento, por exemplo, ele referenciaria o elemento que chamou o evento.

Por isso muitas vezes quando precisamos do `this` dentro de uma função `forEach` dentro de uma função de evento, guardamos o `this` do evento numa variável para usá-lo dentro da função do `forEach`:

```js
document.getElementById("botao").addEventListener("click", function(){

   let el = this; // guarda o this numa variável
   ['a','b'].forEach(function(valor){

      // a variável "el" é igual ao this do evento
      // pois aqui o this referencia o objeto global
      if(el.value == valor){
         el.style.background = "red";
      }

   });

});
```

```html
<button id="botao" value="b">Clique-me</button>
```

Answer (score 5):

Porque não foi feito o binding do `this` nessa função.

Talvez a melhor maneira de enxergar o `this` seja como um argumento qualquer: ele tem que ser inicializado com algum valor.

Quando você invoca um método (invoca uma função através de um objeto), o próprio JS inicializa o `this` com uma referência ao objeto:

```js
var obj = {
  val: 10,
  
  logValue() {
    console.log(this.val);
  }
}

obj.logValue();
```

Funciona, certo? O `this` foi inicializado com uma referência a `obj`, e portanto `this.val` é o mesmo que `obj.val`.

Agora o que acontece se desvincularmos a função do `obj`?

```js
var obj = {
  val: 10,
  
  logValue() {
    console.log(this.val);
  }
}

var func = obj.logValue;
func();
```

Não funciona mais. `this` não se refere mais a `obj`, se refere a `window`, pois não foi feito o binding da função com `obj`.

---

Em nota, o binding pode ser feito manualmente também:

```js
var obj = {
  val: 10,
  
  logValue() {
    console.log(this.val);
  }
}

var func = obj.logValue;
func.bind(obj)();
```

Isso é basicamente o que acontece quando você faz `obj.logValue()`, o binding é feito automaticamente para você.

Se você conhece Python, é similar a forma de que o primeiro argumento é automaticamente inicializado com uma referencia ao objeto, quando você invoca uma função através de um objeto.

Comment: Impressão minha ou esses `logValue` tem um erro de sintaxe?